# Reboot/shutdown causes BIOS not to find startup

Tags: boot, bios, restart

Good evening. 
So installing ubuntu server works just fine and I can add stuff to the server and etc. 
However when I reboot/shutdown my server computer the BIOS says it can't find the start up file. i've reinstalled it three times yet no luck.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the output of `efibootmgr` command before rebooting.

The installation process might have configured the EFI boot options wrong so now the EFI firmware is unable the find the boot image. Or the system's boot images isn't located at a standard place in the EFI boot partition.

It's also possible to check and manually configure this with a live boot image.

If that's the issue, I'll be able to assist with more info.